# SQL distinct rows and count

Tags: sql, count, row, distinct

I have a table like this:

```
Id  CookieId
--------------------------------
4   13ab1dc1bac-ef74565ea9ff5ba8
4   13b474728b3-6cf7bf445e311c59
4   13b474728b3-6cf7bf445e311c59
4   13a1b545ebf-20c86b23c91ad2c5
4   13a1b545ebf-20c86b23c91ad2c5
```

The result should be only the distinct rows:

```
Id  CookieId
--------------------------------
4   13ab1dc1bac-ef74565ea9ff5ba8
4   13b474728b3-6cf7bf445e311c59
4   13a1b545ebf-20c86b23c91ad2c5
```

More of that if I can get the count of the rows would be also good.

```
Id      count(CookieId)
-----------------------
4       3
```

How can I achieve this two result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get unique records in result use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, CookieId
FROM Table1
```

Result:

```
| ID |                     COOKIEID |
-------------------------------------
|  4 | 13ab1dc1bac-ef74565ea9ff5ba8 |
|  4 | 13b474728b3-6cf7bf445e311c59 |
|  4 | 13a1b545ebf-20c86b23c91ad2c5 |
```

To get count of unique `CookieId` use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT` function like this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CookieId) AS `COUNT`
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
```

Result:

```
| ID | COUNT |
--------------
|  4 |     3 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc870d/5)

Answer (score 2):

First to select the distinct values use

```
SELECT DISTINCT CookieId, Id 
FROM YourTable;
GO
```

This is only working because you have duplicates across two columns. To get the count of those values use

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(DISTINCT CookieId)
FROM YourTable;
GROUP BY Id;
GO
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this query

```
select Id,count(CookieId) from table_name group by CookieId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id, CookieId, count(1) as Amount
from Table1 group by Id, CookieId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT(`CookieId`),Id, COUNT(CookieId) FROM
 `tablename` GROUP BY `CookieId`
```